# Github Desktop: Rebase vs Merge Commit, to keep a fork up to date

Tags: git, github, git-merge, desktop, git-rebase

My work flow to contribute to a repo, is

1. Create a fork of the upstream
2. Clone the fork to my local
3. Push changes to my fork
4. Create a PR to merge my change into upstream

Sometimes while I am working on my change, other devs might commit their changes into the upstream, so I want to do a rebase which will bring my fork up to date. But I have noticed that in the below scenario, Rebase and Merge Commit gave me different response,

The way I tested it is as follow:

1. I created a fork of the upstream
2. I cloned my fork to my local using GitHub Desktop, and set current branch to my fork branch
3. I then made a change in upstream/master branch and committed it
4. when I clicked "Rebase current branch", it tells me the current branch is up-to-date as below:
   [image: screenshot]
5. when I clicked "Merge into current branch", it detects a change in the upstream:
   [image: screenshot]
   `upstream/master` is the branch in the upstream, and `muti/master` is the branch in my fork.

My question is, why rebase doesn't detect any change, while the merge and commit does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note first that if you have access to the `upstream` repository, you don't have to fork it in order to push a fix branch and initiate a PR (Pull Request).

You can do all that directly in the upstream repository.

Second, the rebase would only work if the current branch has a divergent history from `upstream/master`.
If the current branch HEAD is an ancestor of `upstream/master`, the rebase (of the current branch on top of `upstream/master`) would be a no-op.
But a merge (of `upstream/master` into the current branch) would not, since from the point of view of the current branch, there is one commit (done in upstream/master) that it does not have.

Comment: Thanks. for 1st, yea I understand, it's just a process we are required to follow. for 2nd, sorry I don't quite understand. I thought a rebase would check if anything committed in upstream but hasn't been brought into origin (which is my fork) yet?

Comment: @user6266816 From your steps, I wasn't sure if you made any modification in your branch. It looked like you only modified upstream/master.

Comment: yea, I only made a change to upstream/master, as I wans trying to replicate the behaviour that other devs merge a change into upstream, I want to test if a rebase on my end would pick that up or not.

Comment: @user6266816 You need to make a change both in `upstream/master` *and* in your own current branch in order to test both rebase and merge.